# Using model variable as a variable in View that will be populated using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing, strongly-typed-view

How can I use the variable in `Model` without using it as an input field? I have 1 unused variable in `Model` which is the `userId`. My `JavaScript` below populates the fields in the `View` depending on the clicked row. I'm planning to populate also the `userId` so I can use it in my Update button. How do I use `m => m.userId` as a variable?

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.userDesc)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userDesc)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.userStatus)
Active @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.userStatus, true)
Inactive @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.userStatus, false)
```

Model

```
public string userId { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]

[Display(Name = "User")]
public string userDesc { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Status")]
public string userStatus { get; set; }
```

part of JavaScript

```
//columnData - represents the column index in my table
//fieldId - id of the fields (e.g. text = userDesc, radio = userStatus)

for (i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) {

    var elmntType = document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).getAttribute("type");

    if (elmntType == "text") {

        document.getElementById(fieldId[i]).value = rowSelected.cells[i].innerHTML.trim();

    } else if (elmntType == "radio") {

        var status = rowSelected.cells[i].innerHTML.trim();

        if(status == "Active") {
            $('input[name="' + fieldId[i] + '"][value="True"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('input[name="' + fieldId[i] + '"][value="False"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: Did just someone put a down vote on my question!? I think it's a valid one. This is not a duplicate question and I posted my codes. Jeez.

Comment: Are you wanting to assign the value of `userId` to a javascript varaiable? - you can use `var id = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.userId));`. Or you could add the value as a `data-*` attribute of a html element (and get it using `var id = $(element).data('....');`

Comment: @PhilipSy: If you hover over the downvote button, you'll see the description: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." In fact this question is a duplicate of about a hundred others here on SO. It's just that there's so many variations on how it's presented they often aren't closed as such. Nevertheless, they all revolve around the asker not understanding the fundamental concept of client-server. In other words, no research effort. I didn't downvote you, but it seems perfectly valid to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use variables contained in `Model` without using the `m => m.A` notation.
Anywhere in your view, you can do something like that : `<h1>Hi @Model.userDesc</h1>`

Now, if you want to use your `Model`'s variables in JS code, you can achieve with 3 ways :

1. Embed your JS code in your view so you can use `@Model.userId` anywhere you want.
2. Externalize in a .js file and initialize the JS code from your view passing `@Model.userId`

Plus, if you want to update the `userId` variable from JS code, you have to store it in a hidden field in order to manipulate it.